# Как найти ряд с максимальной разницей нескольких столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

В фрейме данных, связанным с кино, надо найти максимальную прибыль с фильма (рассчитывается как profit = revenue - budget).

Как найти конкретный ряд по типу того, что на картинке:

[image: Ряд]

, а не число, которое можно получить через `.max()`?

Пытался также через `.idxmax()`, но не знаю как через полученный `id` найти ряд.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методами [DataFrame.assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) и [DataFrame.nlargest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
res = (df
       .assign(profit=df["revenue"] - df["budget"])
       .nlargest(1, columns=["profit"]))
```